# Sequence in filter - does it matter?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Lets consider that we have following boolean condition:
`A,B,C,D`.
Now we would like to filter list according to them:
`list.stream().filter(x -> A).filter(x -> B).filter(x -> C).filter(x -> D)`

`list.stream().filter(x -> A && B && C && D)`

What way is better ? I mean efficiency and elegance.

Comment: It's easier to extract `x -> A`, `x -> B` ... as predicates and e.g. pass them as parameters.

Comment: In short, stop caring about performance. Care about readability and  maintainability.

Comment: @AdamKotwasinski I can'd understand what do you write. So first or second version ? And what do you mean saying about easier to extract ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of raw efficiency, the combined filter will be slightly better. But the cases where that actually makes a difference for your application should be very rare. I'd treat it as [premature optimization](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization).

And the cost of introducing such optimizations is tightly-coupled, error-prone code that does to many things at once and can't easily be tested.

If you follow the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) strictly, then one filter should only apply one criterion. It makes your code more obvious and readable, even though it may cost you some nanoseconds.

Comment: I would have thought "significantly" rather than "slightly", though that may change as Java evolves.  You are right on the premature optimization point ... especially if we count asking questions about this on StackOverflow as part of the (world wide!) optimization effort.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of efficiency, there is a *slight* drawback with the first example; there will be more objects created when chaining multiple intermediate `filter` operations together, the reason being that each `filter` intermediate operation returns a new stream. whereas with the other approach you don't have that *slight* overhead.

> What way is better ? I mean efficiency and elegance.

you should go with whichever of the two you want as the performance difference is *minimal*.

Comment: Doesn't make sense. The number of streams created doesn't depend on the size of the collection. Only on the number of intermediate operations. You have one stream of N elements. If you apply a filter, you create 1 additional stream on M (M <= N) elements. A stream doesn't make any copy of elements. It's not a collection. Just a pipeline of operations.

Comment: @JBNizet I think you misunderstood me here. I didn't say the number of streams depends on the size of the collection. nevertheless will edit it to clarify that.